# How do we derive the Hamiltonian of the Wilson Loop Action?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, quantum-chromodynamics, wilson-loop, lattice-gauge-theory

I'm reading Fradkin and Susskind's 1978 paper "Order and disorder in gauge systems and magnets" to try and understand how they derive the Hamiltonian for the U(1) compact lattice gauge theory. The Wilson loop action is 
\begin{align*}
S = -\beta \sum_{n \in \Lambda } \sum_{\mu , \nu}  Re(U_{\mu \nu}(n)) = -\beta \sum_{n \in \Lambda } \sum_{\mu , \nu} \cos \left(\theta_\mu(n) + \theta_\nu(n+\hat{\mu}) - \theta_\mu(n+\hat{\nu}) - \theta_\nu(n) \right)
\end{align*}
What I want to know is how to first extract the Lagrangian from the Action above, and then do I just apply the Legendre transform to get the Hamiltonian? because the paper does some weird manipulation in the time-like part of the Action.

My attempt: 
I was able to split the action into 2 parts: a time-like part and a space-like part :
\begin{gather*}
S = S_e + S_m \\
S_e = -\beta \sum_{n \in \Lambda} \sum_{k = 1}^3 \cos(a\dot{\theta}_k(n)) \\
S_m = -\beta \sum_{n \in \Lambda} \sum_{i = 2}^3 \sum_{j = 1}^{i-1} 
\cos \left(\theta_i(n) + \theta_j(n+\hat{i}) - \theta_i(n+\hat{j}) - \theta_j(n) \right),
\end{gather*} 
where $ \dot{\theta}_k(n) = \frac{\theta_k(n+\hat{t}) - \theta_k(n)}{a} $, where $a$ is the lattice spacing.
I know that I'm somehow supposed to have a Hamiltonian that consists of an electric (time-like) and a magnetic (space-like) part, hence why i split the action.